# Why is it TypeError in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, typeerror

TypeError is started from JoinNavigator.

```
export class JoinNavigator extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <JoinStackNavigator
        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
          this._getCurrentRouteName(currentState)
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  _getCurrentRouteName(navState) {
    if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
      this._getCurrentRouteName(navState.routes[navState.index])
    } else {
      console.log("Current Route Name:", navState.routeName);
      let regExp = /^AskStep/;
      if(navState.routeName.match(regExp)){
        this.props._changeVisibleStatusBar(); //It's located at this.
      }
    }
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = ({app}) => {
  return app;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    _changeVisibleStatusBar: () => {
      dispatch(changeVisibleStatusBar(false))
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(JoinNavigator);
```

Actions.
When I call the action at JoinNavigator, It's works. No problem.

```
import {
  APP_STATUS_BAR
} from './types'

export const changeVisibleStatusBar = (val) => {
  return {
    type: APP_STATUS_BAR,
    payload: {hiddenStatusBar: val}
  }
};
```

Reducer. 
You can see "console.log".
It's works. 
All of data parameter displayed well on React Native Debugger.

```
import {
  APP_STATUS_BAR
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  hiddenStatusBar: false,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case APP_STATUS_BAR:
      console.log(action); //It's works well.
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Clearly, 
- Action is called from JoinNavigator.
- It's dispatched and passed with Action to Reducer. (I saw console.log)

So... Why is it TypeError?

TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

```
This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at JoinNavigator.js:60)
    in JoinNavigator (created by Connect(JoinNavigator))
    in Connect(JoinNavigator) (at SceneView.js:17)
    in SceneView (at CardStack.js:385)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
.....
```

Needs help.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to `React-Native`!

Comment: @triandicAnt Hi triandicAnt :) I feel good with React-Native but It's different other things. (like Android, jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the redux dev tools in chrome or Firefox to inspect what actions are being triggered. Some undefined action is getting dispatched, but it’s hard to know where from